# "Unable to debug executable since a debug session is in progress." stop xcode GDB Debugger from AppleScript

Tags: iphone, xcode, mobile

I'm trying to stop a running GDB inside of xcode using my AppleScript that builds and runs my iPhone PhoneGap apps.

It throws this error if the app is already running when I'm testing:

"Unable to debug executable since a debug session is in progress."

I need to get it to stop the current debugger before rebuilding.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

It took me a while, but here it is!

```
tell application "Xcode"
    activate

    tell sub menu of menu item 7 of main menu
            call method "performActionForItemAtIndex:" of it with parameters {4}
    end tell
end tell
```

Answer (score 0):

Just ended up using `killall Xcode`